# How to redirect all traffic to Angular app inside Rails (using Nginx)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx

Ok, basically I'm using Nginx, Passenger, Rails and Angular. I've created an Angular app that compiles to Rails' public folder. Rails provides the API underneath the Angular app.

I'd like to have all traffic that comes `www.mydomain.com/admin` to this `admin.html` file located in the public directory. I've got a route in Rails `config/routes.rb` pointing to `admin.html` like so:

```
match     '/admin/*all' => redirect("/admin.html"), via: 'get'
```

But that doesn't seem to do the trick. I also would like Nginx to redirect all traffic with `admin/*` to this `admin.html` file in public folder.

By the way, the `admin.html` is the Angular app.

**EDIT: The Angular app is not being served by Rails**

At the moment, there's no views in Rails at all. Rails is just an API underneath a standalone Angular app that happens to be in the public directory inside Rails app. I've chosen this approach at this stage for two reasons: One I might deploy the Angular on a separate server at later stage, but not right now. So keeping the Angular completely independent and separate is a good idea. Two, At the moment, keeping the Angular on top of the Rails app will help reduce latency.

The whole setup is part of an experience that will evolve, I wanted to keep my options open moving forward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a route to an action that loads the angular application, then have your normal resources (probably APIs) in the `routes.rb` afterwards

routes.rb

```
match 'admin', to: 'admin#angular', via: :all
```

admin_controller.rb

```
def angular
    render 'layouts/admin'
end
```

Then `layouts/admin.html.haml` is your Angular application

Reference: https://thinkster.io/angular-rails/ (very good tutorial btw)

Comment: This approach wouldn't quite work because the Angular app is not part of the Rails in a sense that the js, css, etc are not being served by Rails. There's no `layout/admin` as there's no layout at all. Rails is just the API underneath (at the moment anyway) and there's no views in it whatsoever.

Comment: You need to server the Angular application via some server, so in my opinion you either use Rails to do that (you can have the view rendered without any layouts `render "someview", layout: false` ) or you'll use Nginx separate from rails to server your Angular app in that case you will add the routes to `nginx` configurations and `routes.rb` inside your rails app won't have a clue about the `/admin` path it will just act as API